# IMPALA: Filter data with string date format

Tags: date, impala

I have table with 2 fields with date: value_day (string, format 2021-02-01) and date_part(string, format 20210201). I need to select evrything with filter on date >= 01.01.2021.

| date_part | value_day | client | segment | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | 2021-01-01 | AAAA | 1 | 123 |
| 20210201 | 2021-02-01 | BBBB | 2 | 456 |
| 20210301 | 2021-03-01 | CCCC | 3 | 789 |

How can I do it?

SQL to_date does not work in Impala language.

Comment: Please add sample table data to your question.

Comment: added table above

Answer (score 2):

Convert first field to timestamp like below -

```
to_timestamp(date_part, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Then apply filter like this -

```
to_timestamp(date_part, 'yyyyMMdd') >= to_timestamp('01/01/2021', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```